# R: find position of the first value <1, whereas all following values have to be <1 as well

Tags: r, function, find

I have to find the suitable value of the variable "time" for the first value below 1 in "disMean", whereas all following values of "disMean" are below 1 as well.

my data structure looks like following:

```
measure = c(rep(1, 1, 18), rep(2,1,18))
ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)
disMean = c(1.5, 1.3, 0.8, 1.2, 0.87, 0.6, 0.8, 1.2, 1.2, 0.9, 0.87, 0.81, 1, 0.66, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 3.5, 1.2, 2.4, 1.5, 0.9, 0.8, 1.2, 0.7, 0.65, 0.54, 0.3, 0.4, 1.6, 1.11, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1)

 time = c(330, 400, 450, 200, 230, 240, 100, 200, 300, 330, 400, 450, 200, 230, 240, 100, 200, 300, 330, 400, 450, 200, 230, 240, 100, 650, 300, 330, 400, 450, 200, 230, 240, 100, 200, 300)
 matrix = cbind(ID, disMean, time, measure)
 data = as.data.frame(matrix)
```

In this case, the desired value of "disMean" for participant 1 in measure 1 (first < 1 && all following values <1) = 0.87 on position 5, the suitable value of "time" = 230 (this number is, what I need). In a second step, these "time-values should be stored in a new variable (let's call it time_below1) for each participant and each measure. Which should look like following in the example:

```
time_below1 <- c(rep(230, 1,6), rep(330, 1, 6), rep(230, 1, 6), rep(230,1,6), rep(650, 1, 6), rep(240,1,6))
```

I wrote the following function and for-loop for solving this problem, but I'm stucking at the problem of "give me the position of the value, where all following values are below 1 as well." (see function below)

Maybe you can help me out here!
Thanks so much!

function:

```
findValue <- function(df, measurement, participant){

# filter dataframe to one participant and one measure
df = df%>%
 filter(measure == measurement)%>%
 filter(ID == participant)

for (x in nrow(df)){
  for (y in 1:5){
    if (df$disMean[x] < 1 && df$disMean[x+y] < 1) {df$trigger == TRUE}
    position <- which(df$trigger == TRUE)
   }
 }
value = df$time[position]
value = rep(value, 1, length(df$ID))

return(value)
}
```

to run the function for the dataframe I use following for-loop:

```
df$time_below1 <- NA
  for (j in 1:length(unique(df$measure))){
    for (i in 1:length(unique(df$ID))){
       df$time_below1[which(df$measure== j & df$ID == i)] <- findValue(data,j,i)
       }
     }
```

Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "all following values <1"? As I see, there are still values in disMean > 1 and position > 5 (e.g. 1.2, pos 8). - Is participitant 1 equal to ID == 1? Do you only consider disMean values with the same ID?

Comment: participant 1 == ID 1, true.
In the real dataset, one measure of one participant encompasses around 1000 values. I'm looking for the value, where the disMean value goes below 1 and stays below 1. So if the value would jump over 1 again (as in the example for ID == 1, measure == 1 on position 4), this value below 1 can be neglected. Might this be clearer now?
But I see your point with position > 5. I choosed this number as a aquivalent to "nrow()" . But that can't work out here of course - stupid!

Comment: #alright I see, per measure and ID....

Comment: did you try something like: `df<-subset(data,ID==1 & measure==1)
min(which(rev(as.numeric(df$disMean<1))==0))` and then either loop through every possible combination of ID and measure or using dplyr as you did...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
findVal <-function(df, measurement, participant){
  df = df %>%
    filter(measure == measurement)%>%
    filter(ID == participant)

  out<-min(which(rev(as.numeric(df$disMean<1))==0))
  return(out)
}
```

That returns the position.

```
findVal <-function(df, measurement, participant){
  df = df %>%
    filter(measure == measurement)%>%
    filter(ID == participant)

  pos<-min(which(rev(as.numeric(df$disMean<1))==0))
  out<-rev(df$disMean)[pos-1]
  return(out)
}
```

That should return the value.

Comment: note the -1 for the indexing. surely, this can be done nicer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort and your help!
Hell, yeah, the [-1] does the trick! Great, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know if I understand the problem but if you want to get the position or index number of the first element of `disMean` that is less than 1 and a segment of the following also are less than 1, this function may be of help. It returns an index number and the corresponding `time` value.

```
findBelow <- function(x){
    r <- rle(x$disMean < 1)
    r$values[r$values][r$lengths[r$values] == 1] <- FALSE
    less <- inverse.rle(r)
    less <- c(less[1], diff(less) > 0)
    result <- list(index = which(less), time = x$time[less])
    result
}

findBelow(data)
#$index
#[1]  5 10 14 23 26 33
#
#$time
#[1] 230 330 230 230 650 240
```